# Books about signal processing with a biology or health basis

Tags: reference-request

I've already seen [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/427/what-resources-are-recommended-for-an-introduction-to-dsp) and [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36734/recommended-signal-processing-books) questions about books and references, but all of them are directed for someone who has a background in engineering or a related field.

Are there any good introduction books or other references for someone with a biology or health basis?

Comment: Can you please make the question a little bit more specific? What sort of background are you refering to? Mathematical modeling is (potentially) everywhere. Do you have a particular focus?

Comment: I'm looking for a very basic introduction, with an approach and examples related to the fields above.

Comment: Be careful, sometime books that claim to be to simple, turn up to be too broad. I suggest start reading, "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" by Richard G. Lyons. It is great and comprehensive and yet easy to understand.

Comment: Have you found your answers yet?

Comment: @Ooker Not yet.